# laravel 4 why send content-type when sending json?

Tags: php, laravel

In the book of laravel I read, and also my co-worker who has experience with laravel said that generating JSON I should in laravel way.

Why do I need to do this:

```
Route::get('markdown/response', function()
{
    $data = array('iron', 'man', 'rocks');
    return Response::json($data);
});
```

As I read it sends also content-type header when using this.

When I was using codeigniter I used to do simply this:

```
echo json_endode($data);
```

and never ever ever had any problems. Even if it is not set content type. Actually I dont know maybe php sets it automatically, but since I did not have problems, I did not care.

And when using 'new' technology I really want to know why it is better than good old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it worked doesn't mean it wasn't wrong. JSON isn't HTML, so `text/html` is an inaccurate `Content-Type` for it.

Sending the correct header means libraries like jQuery understand what sort of data they're getting back, and thus are able to handle it on their own without guidance. Browsers may also do things like pretty-printing the JSON data or making it otherwise easier to read.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that with jquery I did not need to just pasreJSON or add 'json' parameter and it automatically see this as object. Still this is not huge thing imo. But better.

Answer (score 5):

With respect, by not providing a `content-type` header, you were doing it "wrong" when coding in CodeIgniter.

Most clients (browsers, ajax requests, especially jQuery) can still can guess how to handle the response correctly and so probably "just worked" for you. You were likely always implicitly returning a `Content-Type: text/html` with your response, which is a default header in CodeIgniter.

You should **always** return a proper content type with your HTTP responses so the consuming client knows how to treat this content. **Note that this is a [mechanism of HTTP as defined in specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), not specific to any framework or even a language.**

```
Response::json()
```

The above code is just a convenience function, where Laravel will automatically set the `application/json` header for you, as well as convert an array of data into JSON format. The only effective difference from your CodeIgniter code is the setting of the header, as you've pointed out.

It's worth noting that the Response object extends Symfony's response object, which is very "powerful" - in other words, it's a very good implementation of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 4):

The response object returned from `Response::json` (and other `Response` static methods) are highly modifiable.

```
$response = Response::json($data);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

You can check for more available methods in the Laravel and Symfony code API.

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.Response.html
http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are trying to do with the route. if you only want to return json data you can just return json_encode($data) and that will work, To actually return a json response for use with something like an ajax request you need the headers set properly or the accepting route just thinks its getting a string. Response::json is for setting the response which sets the headers appropriately.

Comment: I dont need to set content type when using ajax request. At least with codeigniter I used ton of ajax requests and in javascript it worked fine. At least with jquery or backbone.js. So still I dont get :)